# Mandrill SMTP giving EOFError: end of file reached errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, resque, mandrill, rails-activejob

We use Mandrill to send transactional email from our Rails application (on Heroku).

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port      => 587,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => 'login',
  :domain => ENV['URL_OPTIONS_HOST'],
}
```

When we send email, we use ActiveJob with deliver_later, to send email in the background with Resque.

Occasionally, perhaps once every 2-3 days, we get the following error:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
File "/app/bin/rake" line 8 in <main>
....
"queue_name": "production_mailers", "job_class": "ActionMailer::DeliveryJob"
```

I think this caused by an SMTP timeout issue from Mandrill.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error? Is it best to retry the failed email, and if so how can this be achieved with ActiveJob and Resque?

Comment: We've been seeing these sorts of issues for a really long time, now on Rails 6. The jobs re-run and eventually get through, but they create a lot of noise in our error tracker. Did you ever find a way to deal with them?

Answer (score 4):

I'm also seeing this problem. It does not happen with every send and most of my sends are done from resque jobs. I wonder if this is a transient problem on mandrill's side or a network problem.

Comment: Yes, I think it is caused by occasional unavailability of Mandrill's SMTP server or other network issues. I've not found the best work around for this yet.

Comment: +1, we're seeing it occasionally as well. Thinking about moving over to API based sending. Either of you find a fix for this yet?